# A single click-event for many buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Window with many buttons (btn_1, btn_2, btn_3 ... btn_81) and instead to create a click-event for each button like this:

```
private void btn_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (backColor != null)
        btn_1.Background = backColor;
}

private void btn_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (backColor != null)
        btn_2.Background = backColor;
}
```

I meant to create only one click-event and get somehow the name of the button I clicked to perform the action. The action performed with the click-event is for each button the same: they must change their background.

I hope I could explain my issue.
TIA!

Comment: find a way to dynamically create 81 buttons instead.

Comment: `object sender` <==

Comment: The answers below are all correct, but the approach feels clunky. You should look or your case-specific way to create these buttons dynamically (most likely with itemsControl(a) bound to collection(s) of appropriate models. If you can provide a little more detail about your program, I can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your XAML you can bind the buttons click events to the same handler:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="btn1" x:Name="btn1" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="btn2" x:Name="btn2" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="btn3" x:Name="btn3" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```
    Brush backColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        if (btn != null && backColor != null)
            btn.Background = backColor;
    }
```

Comment: I'd also check if `btn` is null after the "cast"

Answer (score 4):

Just add same event to each button. In your case add `btn_1_Click`. You can do that like:

```
btn1.Click += btn1_Click;
btn2.Click += btn1_Click;
btn3.Click += btn1_Click;
...
```

or

```
btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
btn3.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
...


private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
   private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Equals(sender, bt1))
        {

        }
        else if(Equals(sender, bt2))
        {

        }
    }
```

**xaml**

```
<Button Content="Button 1" Name="bt1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
<Button Content="Button 2" Name="bt2" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
```